# selectableItemBackground with white background on tablayout?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-xml

I had a tab layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/background_white" />
```

For implementing ripple animation I have to change the background to

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

It enables the ripple animation but the default color is kind of gray and  I want my background to be a customized color like white, I also tried

```
android:background="@color/white"
app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

But It doesn't appear when the background color is white,

I just don't know what's the reason that it doesn't work on white background?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

finally, I find out how to get a background and selectable item together. first you need to declare two styles in your `styles.xml`, like below

```
<style name="SelectableItemTheme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/light_gray</item>
</style>
<style name="SelectableItemBackground">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/SelectableItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>
```

And after that you assign it as an style parameter to tab-layout and put the color that you want from it,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   android:id="@+id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="60dp"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   style="@style/SelectableItemBackground"
   android:background="@color/background_login"/>
```